# Haskell: Understanding the pure function for Applicative functors

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, applicative

I am learning about Applicative Functors and the pure function has the following type declaration:

```
pure :: a -> f a
```

I understand that the pure function takes a value of any type and returns an applicative value with that value inside it. So if the applicative instance was `Maybe`, `pure 3` would give `Just 3`.

However, what happens when you apply pure to a value that's already inside an applicative value? E.g. what happens if you do something like `pure Just 3`?

Comment: You'll probably find the results much easier to understand if you distinguish between `pure Just 3` and `pure (Just 3)`.

Comment: Do you mean: `(pure (Just 3)) :: Maybe (Maybe Integer)` == `Just (Just 3)`?

Comment: FWIW, `Just` can be thought of as a function with signature `a -> Maybe a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What happens when you apply pure to a value that's already inside an applicative value?

It just gets wrapped in an additional layer. The end result is an applicative value nested inside another applicative value.

> E.g. what happens if you do something like `pure Just 3`?

This is an interesting question, although probably not for the reasons you meant. The important point here is to distinguish `pure (Just 3)` — which was probably what you meant — from `pure Just 3 = (pure Just) 3`, which is what you wrote. This gives two scenarios:

- `pure (Just 3)` simply applies `pure` to the value `Just 3`, which — as I discussed above — gives `Just (Just 3)`, which is a nested applicative value.
- `(pure Just) 3` is an interesting case. Recall the types of `pure` and `Just`:

  ```hs
  pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
  Just :: a -> Maybe a
  -- so:
  pure Just :: Applicative f => f (a -> Maybe a)
  ```

  In other words, `pure Just` takes the function `Just` and wraps it inside an applicative value.

  Next, we want to take `pure Just` and apply it to a value `3`. But we can’t do this, since `f (a -> Maybe a)` is a value, not a function! So `(pure Just) 3` should result in a type error.

  …except it turns out to typecheck just fine! So we’re missing something. In this case, it turns out there is an applicative instance for functions:

  ```hs
  instance Applicative ((->) r) where
    pure x = \r -> x
    (<*>) = _irrelevant_here
  ```

  The syntax is a bit funny, but it basically means that `r -> ...` is an applicative. This particular instance is known as the *Reader monad*, and it’s very widely used. (For more about this particular data type, see e.g. [here](https://mmhaskell.com/monads-4) or [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-reader-monad-part-1-1e4d947983a8).) The idea is that `r -> a` can compute an `a` given an `r` input; in this case, `pure x` creates a function which ignores its input and returns `x` always, and `f <*> x` feeds the `r` input into both `f` and `x`, then combines the two. In this case, we’re only using `pure`, so it’s easy to evaluate `(pure Just) 3` by hand:

  ```hs
  (pure Just) 3
  = (\r -> Just) 3
  = Just
  ```

  So the idea here is that `pure` wraps `Just` in an applicative value, which in this case happens to be a function; then, we apply this function to `3`, which gets rid of the wrapper to reveal the original `Just`.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, pure has the type:

```
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

To make things simpler, think of the kind of f

```
:k f 
f :: * -> *
```

and the kind of `a` is `*`

then the type of `a`, is just `a`, any `a`, the most polymorphic of all (but with kind `*` remember). So you don't really care the value of a, you just have a restriction, and that's the `typeclass` Applicative, and the kind of `f` (remember `* -> *`)

so in this case:

```
gchi> pure 3 :: Maybe Int
ghci> Just 3
```

here `f` is `Maybe` and `a` is `3`

In the same way

```
gchi> pure $ Just 3 :: Maybe (Maybe Int)
gchi> Just (Just 3)
```

here `f` is again `Maybe` and `a` is `Just 3`

and you can play a little changing the type to pure:

```
gchi> pure 3 :: [Double]
ghci> [3.0]
```

here, `f` is [], and `a` is `3`

same way

```
ghci> pure [3] :: [[Double]]
ghci> [[3.0]]
```

finally here, `f` again, is `[]` and `a` is [3]